# Asymptotic formula for the integral sequence s(n)

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, number-theory, stirling-numbers, additive-combinatorics

Prove that there exists a sequence $A_{0}, A_{1}$, . . . of rational polynomials $A_{i}(x)\in \mathrm{Q}[x]$ with $A_{i}$ of degree $i$ such that
$$
s(n)=\frac{n^{n-1}}{(1-\log 2)^{n-1/2}e^{n}}(\sum_{k=0}^{m}\frac{A_{k}(1-\log 2)}{n^{k}}+o(n^{-m}))
$$
for all $m\in \mathbb{N}$ and $s(n)$ is given by
$$
s(n)=\displaystyle \sum_{i=n+1}^{2n}t_{i,0}(n)
$$
where $t_{i,j}(n)$ is recursively given by 
$$
t_{i,j}(n) = (i-2)t_{i-1,j}(n-1) + t_{i-1,j-1}(n-1) + (i-3)t_{i-2,j}(n-1)
$$
and $i \in \{n+1,...,2n\}$ , $j \in \{0, 1, ...,2n-i\}$ where $n=1,2,3...$

P.S. We know that
$$
2\ \sum_{i=n+1}^{2n}t_{i,0}(n)=\sum_{i=n+1}^{2n}\sum_{j=0}^{2n-i}t_{i,j}(n)+\sum_{i=n}^{2n-2}\sum_{j=0}^{2n-2-i}t_{i,j}(n-1)
$$
for all $n\geq 2$ and first few polynomials $A_{0}, A_{1}$, . . . are
$$
A_{0}\ =\ 1
$$
$$
A_{1}\ =\ \frac{11}{24}-\frac{x}{12}
$$
$$
A_{2}\ =\ \frac{265}{1152}-\frac{47x}{288}+\frac{x^{2}}{288}
$$
$$
A_{3}\ =\ \frac{48703}{414720}-\frac{3649x}{13824}+\frac{107x^{2}}{6912}+\frac{139x^{3}}{51840}
$$
$$
A_{4}\ =\ \frac{2333717}{39813120}-\frac{2019163x}{4976640}+\frac{16489x^{2}}{331776}+\frac{26549x^{3}}{1244160}-\frac{571x^{4}}{2488320}
$$
$$
A_{5}\ =\ \frac{38180761}{1337720832}-\frac{293093189x}{477757440}+\frac{16859263x^{2}}{119439360}+
$$
$$
+\frac{6752203x^{3}}{59719680}-\frac{170729x^{4}}{59719680}-\frac{163879x^{5}}{209018880}
$$

Comment: The definition of $t_{i, j}(n)$ seems incomplete - how do you find $t_{2, 0}(1)$? The recurrent equation you gave is not enough. The same applies to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2709362/modular-properties-of-the-integral-sequence-sn).